# How can I output the Compositor result instead of the Render Result when rendering an animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I have a `File Output` node in the compositor to output my composited images for my animation.  I put the same output filename (e.g. "anim_###.png") in the `Output Properties` area so that I can click `Render` -> `View Animation` from the menu to review my animation.  But when the animation renders, the *Render Result* overwrites the file from the compositor output.

As a workaround, I delete the filename in the `Output Properties` area, render the animation, replace the filename that I just deleted, and then click `View Animation.`  This works, but is tedious and error prone.

As an alternative, I would like to be able to simply view an animation using the output images from the compositor instead of relying on the `Output Properties` settings.  Perhaps I could just write a Python script to pull up the animation playback window?  But a native solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this problem using Python:

```
import bpy

def render(rex_x, res_y):
    oldx = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x
    oldy = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y
    outpath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath

    try:
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = res_x
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = res_y
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = ''
   
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, write_still=False)

    finally:
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = oldx
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = oldy
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = outpath
```

The `try`/`finally` is to put back the original values in case of semi-catastrophic failure (which actually happened to me just now since my script is more complicated than the minimum version posted here).  In my case I also needed to alter the resolution, which cannot be driven using a `Driver`.  So, two birds and all that...